# How to align text vertically and horizontally over image in column column-block in zurb foundation 6

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, text-alignment, zurb-foundation-6

I've tried a lot of approaches to horizontally and vertically center an h4 title over an image, which is inside a column with the "column-block" property in a block-grid in Foundation 6.

I did get it to work somewhat on the first image, but it isn't responsive and I know it isn't right. I can't find anything on the web that addresses this specific issue; I'm surprised it's so hard to resolve.

Here's my code (I still have some inline code because I've been trying various options...):

CSS:

```
.event-row {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 58%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 8%; 
}

.event-title {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
   <div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-3" style="position: relative;">
      <div class="column column-block"> 
         <img src="assets/events/book-release.jpg" width="600" height="600" class="thumbnail" alt="">           
         <div class="row event-row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
              <h4 class="event-title" style="color:white;">
               BOOK PARTIES
              </h4> 
            </div>  
          </div>     
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/tent-event.jpg" width="600" class="thumbnail" alt="">       
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/index/cooking-class-cu.jpg" width="600" class="thumbnail" alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/index/wedding.jpg" width="600" class="thumbnail" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/moulin-rouge-cropped.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/conservatory-lunch-cropped.jpg"  alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/tea-party-cropped.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/rehearsal-dinner-cropped.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div class="column column-block">
          <img src="assets/events/baby-party.jpg" width="600"  class="thumbnail" alt=""> 
        </div>

      </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end body -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use images inside the columns, then you'd be best off using position: absolute for your text.

Foundation has a mixin for this

```
@include absolute-center;
```

which does

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

See example:
https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/qPRVad